# IBOutlet value gets nil when accessed inside a delegate

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, option-type, iboutlet

I have a UIViewController containing a MKMapView in Storyboard. Then I made an outlet of that mapview. From this screen I go to another screen where from a delegate is called back in the first viewcontroller which contains the map. Problem arises when in this delegate method, I try to get the mapview, it always gives me nil. Thus producing "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”)" error.

Here is my code:

1)IBOutlet connection in MapViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
```

2) Delegate method in MapViewController:

```
func didSelectSearchContact(selectedContact: Contacts) -> Void{

let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D  = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(selectedContact.lat, selectedContact.lng)
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.0, 2.0)
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion      = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
print("self.map====== \(self.map)")

 map.region = map.regionThatFits(region)//here comes the crash.
}
```

3) This is How the above delegate is being called from another view controller:

```
let contact = searchResults[indexPath.row] as! Contacts

    self.delegate = MapViewController()
    self.delegate?.didSelectSearchContact(contact)
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong here!! Thanks!

Comment: Show the delegate being setup and called

Comment: Does this code is inside the ViewController class or a sub viewController?

Comment: @GalMarom ViewController class

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: Edit the question, don't add code in comments. Also, add context around the code, where is it, have you checked it was called...

Answer (score 0):

So basically you hold a weak reference to the mapView.
When you leave the ViewController to the new viewController the viewController is being deallocated. Therefore, it lost the pointer to the mapKit and retains it for the memory.
I wouldn't recommend you to change it to a strong pointer but rather save necessary primitives or structures that you will need in the future.
I.e when you operate the segue save the selectedContact.lat, selectedContact.lng or whatever you need.

I think you should have in your new ViewController a separate IBOutlet to the MAPKit that connects to the appropriate view.
In your initialiser just set the mapView's params to focus on the required data

Comment: Actually, I want to bring the selected contacts's lat & long on the map and zoom to show the location. For this I need to have mapview property to set its region. Please let me know if there is any other way I could to this.

Comment: can you attach any sketch or more info? I didn't quite understand what your flow is

Comment: Lets say it this way:

I have a MapViewController with MKMapView in it with an Outlet. From this screen, I push to another view controller called SearchViewController. On this SearchViewController, I perform some action and pop back to MapViewController. Now if I try to access the map view outlet, it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, good 40 minutes to find out the error right in front of my eyes. :P

Problem was that I was trying to assign a new object of my controller when setting the delegate. Also, I was setting the delegate wrong way.

Now the step 3 (see my question) looks like this:

```
let contact = searchResults[indexPath.row] as! Contacts

//self.delegate = MapViewController // this line was the reason of error, so I commented it out
    if (self.delegate  !=  nil){
        self.delegate?.didSelectSearchContact(contact)
    }
```

Hope it helps someone else!!